# When duplicating CrossTab cannot change data format individually

Tags: cognos, cognos-10

In my Cognos report, I have a crosstab which uses Percent as data format for it's fields. call it CT1

I copy/paste CT1 and make CT2. Now CT1 and CT2 both are links to the same Query.

In CT2, I change data format for the columns to Currency.

When I do this change the data format for CT1 also shows as Currency, however in properties grid, I see the data format for CT1 is still Percent.

Answer (score 0):

For your problem, you can create a new data item and name it CT2 and use the data of CT1. Then include both the data items in the same query and change the data format in properties. After this is done, you can use it in your report. CT1 and CT2 will show different data format. Try it , it works.I have tried it myself. If you still receive any error.Reply back.